# Casting Z3 Real into float

Tags: types, floating-point, z3, z3py

Is there a way to cast a `Real` value to a float, so that python can play with the values once z3 is done?

```
x = RealVal("1/3")
print(x.sort())
print(float(x))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you cannot cast a z3 real-value to a float. A z3 real-value is an infinitely precise real-number, and cannot be faithfully represented as a floating point value which has inherent precision limitations.

Instead, you want to convert it to a Python fraction: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fraction-module-in-python which can represent all z3 real-values so long as they are not irrational roots of polynomials. (You can ignore this final comment unless you work with full algebraic-reals in z3.)

To do so, use the `as_fraction` method:

```py
from z3 import *

x = RealVal("1/3")
x2 = x.as_fraction()
print type(x2)
print x2
```

This prints:

```
<class 'fractions.Fraction'>
1/3
```

If you really want, you can then turn that into a float:

```py
x_float = float(x2.numerator) / float(x2.denominator)
print type(x_float)
print x_float
```

This prints:

```
<type 'float'>
0.333333333333
```

but obviously you've now lost precision.

Comment: I was disappointed to discover that apparently it is not possible to convert a `Real` to a `Float64`, a `Float64` to a `IEEEBV`, extract the bits of the `IEEEBV` as a binary value and then use the `struct` python library to cast it to a python `float`.

Comment: That's technically possible, but you have to jump through hoops to do it and you lose precision along the way and the solver will give you lots of unknown results as everything turns horribly non-linear. IEEE BVs are not in the SMT standard, but Z3 has an unsupported non-standard function to get such BVs, but obviously without any guarantees.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin That'd be cool indeed; to be able to do this directly inside z3. But as Christoph pointed out, when I try such conversions `unknown` results become the norm. And that's not surprising when coming from `Int` as it'd let you solve Diophantine equations. But perhaps it can do better with `Real` though I doubt it.

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger Indeed that has been my experience as well. But I always wondered why you get `unknown` even when the quantity you're converting is a known constant. I always felt z3's FP logic didn't propagate constants as aggressively as it can sometimes, but admittedly that's not the most common use case.

Comment: @ChristophWintersteiger As far as I can see, the only passage in which there is loss of precision is `Real -> Float64`, but in SMT-LIB one can choose a suitable *RoundingMode*, whereas in the solution of alias this is not possible. I am not sure what `Float64 -> IEEEBV` does, what I would expect is that it extracts the bits inside a `Float64` value without any change (except for `NaN` that is given a unique representation) and returns some `BV` of *64 bits*.

Comment: [cont.] If `Float64` is compatible with a python `float` (in terms of number of exp/significand bits), then casting the vector of bits to a `float` should be valid and without any loss too because it is a simple matter of re-interpreting a number of machine bytes. I feel like I am missing out some important piece of the equation, because I am not sure where the *unknowns* and the *non-linearity* would come from. If you have the time to clarify this issue I would be quite happy to learn something new. Otherwise, thank you anyway for your comments. :)

Comment: @PatrickTrentin The issue (as I understand it) is that z3 does not realize that it's converting a constant. Instead, it treats it as a symbolic value, and generates a ton of equations first. If it can "solve" all these equations it'd find a solution indeed, but heuristics fail due to non-linearity and it goes to `unknown`. More aggressive constant folding can help in cases like this, but I do agree it's a double-edged sword: It adds complexity to the code and most likely won't help in general since if everything is a constant, why bother with an SMT solver in the first place?

Comment: @alias I was under the impression that the SMT solver is necessary to find a Model for an arbitrarily complex SMT problem. Given a Model, I would expect it to be relatively easy to assign every `Real` variable/expression a constant `Real` value. Why it needs solve non-linear equations to convert such value to some `FP` type?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin My guess is that the "model finder" doesn't communicate early or aggressively enough with the FP routines to detect constants and perform these conversions quickly. But I'm not a developer, that's just my hunch. Cristoph can comment on that.

Comment: Another example: Declare two double-precision floats in z3. Assert that they are some constants. (Doesn't really matter what constants they are.) Declare a third double, and assert that it's the result of the `fp.rem` operation of the two. Z3 takes an inordinately long time to compute the model for this, even though everything involved are constants. My guess is because it "blasts" `fp.rem` before it propagates anything, and generates so many equations that propagating afterwards takes a long time. Some of this is unavoidable, but some of it can be handled with more agressive constant-folding.

Comment: @alias Oh yeah, I can see that. I thought it was possible to encode everything in `LRA` and, only after retrieving a Model, evaluate a `RealToFP` expression over the model without further search. After all, OP appears to need to play with the values only after `z3` is "done".

Comment: Re constants: they are being propagated, but which ones of them to what degree may depend on the tactics and solvers you use (e.g. incremental solver use). If you have a concrete use case feel free to send it to me and I can take a look.

Comment: Re non-linearity rough intuition: the solver can't use all real numbers to satisfy a problem, it can only chose from a very small set of fixed real numbers (the floats), but it can't really tell which ones they are - it basically tries blindly and the FP theory just keeps saying "no". The BV solver is a much better fit for these problems.

Comment: If you need the floats only after the model has been found, you can apply a function when you do the model evaluation (you can call model.eval() with arbitrary terms), but there are also functions that approximate reals (e.g. Z3_get_numeral_decimal_string takes a precision argument), and I think Z3_get_numeral_double might work too.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophWintersteiger, I'm personally more concerned about correctness than speed when it comes to FP theory. https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/2381 has been a sore point for some time now, would be nice to have that fixed. (But I admit, none of this is a show-stopper for anything urgent; just having the bugs ironed out.)

Comment: Yeah, that one is a nasty one. I have identified the parts of the circuit that need fixing, but I estimate that it will take about another two days to get a fix implemented (and I don't have that much time to spend on it right now).